# Calling two images at a time? A better way?

Tags: images, offsets

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the best way to achieve this. I'm trying to load two photos at a time into a  which serves as a slideshow wrapper. Currently i'm repeating a lot of code and just manually setting an offset each time.

My current code works, but it's just very clunky. Here's what it looks like:

```
<div id="engagement">
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            $images = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
                'offset' => 0,
                'posts_per_page' => 2, // show two images at a time
                'update_post_term_cache' => false,
            ) );    
                foreach ($images->posts as $image) {
                ?>
                <div class="six columns mobile-two">
                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'full' ); // get the image ?>
                </div> 
            <?php
            }                               
        ?>                      
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            $images = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
                'offset' => 2,
                'posts_per_page' => 2, // show two images at a time
                'update_post_term_cache' => false,
            ) );    
                foreach ($images->posts as $image) {
                ?>
                <div class="six columns mobile-two">
                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'full' ); // get the image ?>
                </div> 
            <?php
            }                               
        ?>                      
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            $images = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
                'offset' => 4,
                'posts_per_page' => 2, // show two images at a time
                'update_post_term_cache' => false,
            ) );    
                foreach ($images->posts as $image) {
                ?>
                <div class="six columns mobile-two">
                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'full' ); // get the image ?>
                </div> 
            <?php
            }                               
        ?>                      
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems like there has to be a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep - it is pretty inefficient.  Here is a rewrite:

```
<div id="engagement">
    <?php
        $images = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
            'offset' => 0,
            'posts_per_page' => 6, // show six images total
            'update_post_term_cache' => false,
        ) );    
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($images->posts as $image) { 
            if($count % 2==0) echo "<div><div class='row'>";
            echo "<div class='six columns mobile-two'>
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'full' );
            echo "</div>";
            $count++;
            if($count % 2==0) echo "</div></div>";
        }                               
    ?>
</div>
```

The idea here is to just use 1 query to get all six images, and then loop through them.  We are using the modular operator (%) to determine when we are on odd or even items so we know when to add the starting and ending div elements for the row.

Code is just off the top of my head, so it is currently untested...

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I didn't think of the modulo. Your code is almost there. Not sure if I should edit your answer or not, but moving the placeholder <div> inside the loop and moving the counter before the last if does the trick.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer - might help the next guy find his way...